# Angularjs - Delete/Disable option after selected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

What I'm trying to achieve here is to remove/disable the selected role after saving my selection. PLUS, if I press the X button at the panel below to remove my list of selections, I will be able to re-populate the list with the deleted roles recovered.

Screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Choose role]

And at the moment, this is what I have:

controller js: http://pastebin.com/LDYrJQyf

html: http://pastebin.com/39G01ARm

Comment: Barak gave me the idea of unique ID. So I played around by passing the selected item with ng-model then compare the IDs with my original list and if it matches, it will then splice off the index of the for loop. I then use the same approach to my re-addition by grabbing the selectedRoles[i].role and push it into the roles list.

Comment: create a plunker or else it will be difficult becz from your JS u are using $http.get('/skill/get/all/roles')  call

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark this as solved. To do so, please accept/tick an answer below, making a new self-answer if necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `$index`. why not pass the id of `selectedSkills` given that it is an object and has a unique id. It would automatically update the table once you `push` it back.